# How to assign bits from a changing STD_LOGIC output to a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR input

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to this web site and I had a question I was hoping to get help with. I am writing VHDL code for a **LFSR** which consists of a transmitter and receiver.
The transmitter is supposed to generate a random binary number (preamble,which it does) and this binary number then has to be concatenated, but I first need to put it in a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR and that's what im having trouble with.

Here is my code for testbench in which this assignment must take place,thank for any help in advance:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

entity testbench is --definig the entity
end testbench;

architecture tb1 of testbench is

    component transmitter is port(
        clk :in std_logic;
        reset:in std_logic;
        enable:in std_logic;
        output :out std_logic);--output is the random generated binary which i need to pass to a vector
    end component;

    --type bit_vector is array (natural range <>) of bit; --this is so that we can define the whole thing otherwise bit can
    --only be 1 or 0 this allows to define them as vectors

    constant SOF: std_logic_vector(0 to 15) := "0101010100001010";  
    constant trailer: std_logic_vector(0 to 7) := "10111110";
    constant payload: std_logic_vector(0 to 7) := "01110010";
    constant L: std_logic_vector(0 to 7) := "00101110";
    signal preamble: std_logic_vector(0 to 95);

    signal clk , reset, enable : std_logic;--output signal
    signal data_packet: std_logic_vector(0 to 135);
    signal output: std_logic;

begin


    --problem is here
    --my attempt
    get_preamble: process
        variable i: std_logic;--this will be used to walk through the preamble vector and put the out put values in 
        --variable j: std_logic;
    begin

        n1: for i in 0 to 95 loop
            if output = '1' then
                preamble(i) <= '1';
            end if;
        end loop;

        if output = '0' then
            for i in 0 to 95 loop
                preamble(i) <= '0';
            end loop;
        end if;

        wait;
    end process;--end of get_preamble

    concatenation :process 
    begin
        data_packet <= preamble & SOF & L & payload & trailer;
        wait;
    end process;
END tb1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please reduce your code to the minimum that shows the problem.  It is a great help to the readers, and improve your chances of getting a good answer.  You may also want to read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, you're saying you're trying to concatenate  the value `output` with the rest of the `preamble` vector. You should change this:

```
n1: for i in 0 to 95 loop

if output = '1' then
   preamble(i) <= '1';
end if;
     end loop;
if output = '0' then

   for i in 0 to 95 loop

   preamble(i) <= '0';
end loop;
   end if;
```

to this:

```
n1: for i in 0 to 95 loop
  wait until clk'EVENT and clk = '1';
  preamble(i) <= output
end loop;
```

Since you have a clock, try to get each value when you have a positive edge in your clock. You do not need to check the value each time, you can just add it to the vector at once.

**EDIT:** You should either wait for the same things in the other process, or wait for the `preamble` to finish loading its 96 values, depending on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: yes now the values of the output are passed to the preamble vector. But during simulation the first 96 bits of the data packet are showing up as UNDEFINED .

Comment: yep jus needed to change the time so that preamble is full. Your help has been the most efficient.

Comment: @daryoush OK, I've added the comment on my post, since it helped you,

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for something like this?
It will take a stream of 96 bits from "output" and put them in "preamble". Then concatenate preamble to the packet.

```
for i in 0 to 95 loop
   wait until rising_edge(clk);
   preamble(i) <= output;
end loop;

data_packet <= preamble & SOF & L & payload & trailer;
```

Comment: yes the test bench also drives the clk but that's a separate process as it need to run for at least 2550 NS for the full preamble to be generated before repeating it self.

Comment: Then you should use my first suggestion.

Comment: I have and all the values are now passing to the preamble but when I simulated and looked at the data packet and all the values of the preamble were undefined .

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the output from your LFSR. Or perhaps your "concatenation process".

Try moving the concatenation line to the end of the preamble loop. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have done that by adding a wait statement to the concatenation process and now I have the full data packet.